# Parsing Apache logs with bash

Tags: linux, bash, apache, shell, awk

I want to parse an Apache log file such as:

```
1.1.1.1 - - [12/Dec/2019:18:25:11 +0100] "GET /endpoint1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
1.1.1.1 - - [13/Dec/2019:18:25:11 +0100] "GET /endpoint1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
2.2.2.2 - - [13/Dec/2019:18:27:11 +0100] "GET /endpoint1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
2.2.2.2 - - [13/Jan/2020:17:15:13 +0100] "GET /endpoint2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
3.3.3.3 - - [13/Jan/2020:17:15:13 +0100] "GET /endpoint2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
1.1.1.1 - - [13/Feb/2020:17:15:13 +0100] "GET /endpoint2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
4.4.4.4 - - [13/Feb/2020:17:15:13 +0100] "GET /endpoint2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
4.4.4.4 - - [13/Feb/2020:17:15:13 +0100] "GET /endpoint2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
4.4.4.4 - - [13/Feb/2020:17:15:13 +0100] "GET /endpoint2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
```

I need to get list of clients IPs visited per month. I have something like this

```
awk '{print $1,$4}' access.log | grep Dec | cut -d" " -f1 | uniq -c
```

but this is wrong because it counts visits ip per day.

The expected result should be like (indentation doesn't matter):

```
Dec 2019
1.1.1.1 2
2.2.2.2 1
Jan 2020
2.2.2.2 1
3.3.3.3 1
Feb 2020
4.4.4.4 3
1.1.1.1 1
```

where 2 are total amount of visits from 1.1.1.1 ip per Dec 2019.

Could you suggest me an approach how to do it?

Comment: Thank you for your edit but looks like sample input and sample expected output are not in sync. eg--> output has `2019` and `2020` in it but sample input doesn't.

Comment: sure, it just example of output :)

Comment: I get that but for future users who are referring this thread it may be helpful, cheers and you could check my answer too, we could discuss on its comment section too.

Comment: Thanks. I've got your point and changed example and expected result

Comment: The amount of records (10) in the expected output does not match  he actual  number in the sample data (9)

Answer (score 2):

One for GNU awk, that outputs in the order the data was fed in (ie. chronological data such as log records should be output in that order):

```
$ gawk '                     # using GNU awk
BEGIN {
    a[""][""]                # initialize a 2D array
}
{
    split($4,t,/[/:]/)       # split datetime 
    my=t[2] OFS t[3]         # my=month year
    if(!(my in mye)) {       # if current my unseen
        mye[my]=++myi        # update month year exists array with new index
        mya[myi]=my          # chronology is made
    }
    a[mye[my]][$1]++         # update record to a hash
}
END {                        # in the end
    # PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"  # this may work for ordering visits
    for(i=1;i<=myi;i++) {    # in fed order 
        print mya[i]         # print month year
        for(j in a[i])       # then related ips in no particular order
            print j,a[i][j]  # output ip and count
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
Dec 2019
1.1.1.1 2
2.2.2.2 1
Jan 2020
2.2.2.2 1
3.3.3.3 1
Feb 2020
1.1.1.1 1
4.4.4.4 3
```

Comment: Thank you! any way to sort it also by visits? For example: Feb 2020\n
4.4.4.4 3\n 1.1.1.1 1 1

Comment: Probably if you uncomment and edit to: `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"`. Yeah, that seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Though your sample expected output doesn't look to match your shown sample, based on your shown sample output and description, could you please try following. Also since this is a log file I will go with field separators method of `awk` since logs will be of fixed pattern.

```
awk -F':| |-|/+|]' '
{
  ind[$7 OFS $8 OFS $1]++
  value[$7 OFS $8 OFS $1]=$1
}
END{
  for(i in value){
    split(i,arr," ")
    print arr[1],arr[2] ORS value[i],ind[i]
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -F':| |-|/+|]' '                             ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separators as : space - / ] here.
{
  ind[$7 OFS $8 OFS $1]++                        ##Creating ind array whose index is 7th 8th and 1st field and keep increasing value with 1 here.
  value[$7 OFS $8 OFS $1]=$1                     ##Creating value with index of 7th, 8th and 1st field and its value is 1st field.
}
END{                                             ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i in value){                               ##Traversing through value elements here.
    split(i,arr," ")                             ##Splitting i into array arr with delimiter as space here.
    print arr[1],arr[2] ORS value[i],ind[i]      ##Printing 1st and 2nd element of arr with ORS(new line) and array value and ind value here.
  }
}' Input_file                                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried your example but it seems that it doesn't work regarding as expected :(

Comment: @Andrii, I have edited it as per your samples please check now :)

Comment: Thank you! I extended example and expected results and it seems that it counts wrong :(

Comment: @Andrii, edited again, please check it now and let me know then.

Comment: Thank you very much! it works! but don't know how to provide sorted by month/year output because I don't clearly understand how it works :) If you have time and wish could you provide some small explanation to your awk command? I think it would be helpful for plenty of users!

Comment: any way to group it by month and year (for ex. Jan 2020, Feb 2020, Jan 2021) and inside this group sort ip by amount of visits, where higher amount should be on 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LOG_FILE=$1

#regex to find mmm/yyyy
dateUniq=`grep -oP '(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\/\d{4}' $LOG_FILE | sort | uniq`


for i in $dateUniq
do  
    #output mmm yyyy
    echo $i | sed 's/\// /g'
    
    #regex to find ip
    ipUniq=`grep $i $LOG_FILE | grep -oP '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'  | sort | uniq`
    
    for x in $ipUniq
    do  
        count=`grep $i $LOG_FILE |grep -c $x`
        #output count ip
        echo $count $x
    done
    echo
done
```

output:

```
Dec 2019
2 1.1.1.1
1 2.2.2.2

Feb 2020
1 1.1.1.1
3 4.4.4.4

Jan 2020
1 2.2.2.2
1 3.3.3.3
```

Comment: thank you! seems that -P option (perl regexp) doesn't work on MacOS :(

Comment: I think this also could work ipUniq=`grep $i $LOG_FILE | grep -oP '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' |sort | uniq` #regex to find ip

Answer (score 0):

for a quick summarize access log. just run below commands.

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log|awk '{print $1}'|sort -nr |uniq -c |sort -nr |head -n 25
```